# How to use sets in Python to find list membership?

Tags: python, set

Given:

`A = [['Yes', 'lala', 'No'], ['Yes', 'lala', 'Idontknow'], ['No', 'lala', 'Yes'], ['No', 'lala', 'Idontknow']]`

I want to know if `['Yes', X, 'No']` exist within A, where `X` is anything I don't care.

I attempted:

```
valid = False
for n in A:
    if n[0] == 'Yes' and n[2] == 'No':
        valid = True
```

I know `set()` is useful in this type of situations. But how can this be done? Is this possible? Or is it better for me to stick with my original code?

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Why do you think a set would be useful in this case?

Comment: Also, an else clause would probably be more efficient than the sentinel.

Comment: `set()` doesn't maintain any order, and from your code it looks like you're  relying on index positions which is not possible with sets.

Comment: @gefei I want to check for the existence of n[0] == 'Yes' and n[1] == 'No'.

Comment: @elwc -- do you want to know if a sublist `['Yes', 'No']` is in the `A`?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I rely on the index position within individual list in A but do not need an order on the 4 lists within that 1 big list.

Comment: Dear all, I've edited the question to make it more general. Please have a look

Comment: @elwc: How about `valid = any(n[0] == "Yes" and n[2] == "No" for n in A)`?

Comment: @DavidRobinson It works but I don't know why you didn't attempt to answer this question.

Comment: updated my answer with timings: `any(i[0]=='Yes' and i[2] == 'No' for i in A*10000)` actually seems to be the 10 times faster than than the set conversion itself.

Comment: @elwc: Only because there were already half a dozen answers!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

if you want check for existance you can just `['Yes', 'No'] in A`:

```
In [1]: A = [['Yes', 'No'], ['Yes', 'Idontknow'], ['No', 'Yes'], ['No', 'Idontknow']]

In [2]: ['Yes', 'No'] in A
Out[2]: True
```

for the next case try:

```
In [3]: A = [['Yes', 'lala', 'No'], ['Yes', 'lala', 'Idontknow'], ['No', 'lala', 'Yes'], ['No', 'lala', 'Idontknow']]

In [4]: any(i[0]=='Yes' and i[2] == 'No' for i in A)
Out[4]: True
```

or you can possibly define a little func:

```
In [5]: def want_to_know(l,item):
   ...:     for i in l:
   ...:         if i[0] == item[0] and i[2] == item[2]:
   ...:             return True
   ...:     return False

In [6]: want_to_know(A,['Yes', 'xxx', 'No'])
Out[6]: True
```

`any(i[0]=='Yes' and i[2] == 'No' for i in A*10000)` actually seems to be the 10 times faster than than the conversion itself.

```
In [8]: %timeit any({(x[0],x[-1]) == ('Yes','No') for x in A*10000})
100 loops, best of 3: 14 ms per loop

In [9]: % timeit {tuple([x[0],x[-1]]) for x in A*10000}
10 loops, best of 3: 33.4 ms per loop

In [10]: %timeit any(i[0]=='Yes' and i[2] == 'No' for i in A*10000)
1000 loops, best of 3: 334 us per loop
```

Answer (score 3):

Convert your `list` to `set` first, because it will improve the look up time from `O(n)` to `O(1)`:

```
In [27]: A = [['Yes', 'No'], ['Yes', 'Idontknow'], ['No', 'Yes'], ['No', 'Idontknow']]

In [28]: s=set(tuple(map(tuple,A)))

In [29]: s
Out[29]: set([('Yes', 'No'), ('No', 'Idontknow'), ('Yes', 'Idontknow'), ('No', 'Yes')])

In [30]: ('Yes', 'No') in s
Out[30]: True
```

`timeit` comparisions:

```
%timeit ['Yes', 'No'] in A
1000000 loops, best of 3: 504 ns per loop  

%timeit ('Yes', 'No') in s
1000000 loops, best of 3: 442 ns per loop       #winner

%timeit ['No', 'Idontknow'] in A
1000000 loops, best of 3: 861 ns per loop

%timeit ('No', 'Idontknow') in s
1000000 loops, best of 3: 461 ns per loop       #winner
```

**Edit:**

If you're only interested in first and last element:

```
In [69]: A = [['Yes', 'No'], ['Yes', 'Idontknow','hmmm'], ['No', 'Yes'], ['No', 'Idontknow']]

In [70]: s={tuple([x[0],x[-1]]) for x in A} # -1 or 2, change as per your requirement
                                         #or set(tuple([x[0],x[-1]]) for x in A)


In [71]: s
Out[71]: set([('Yes', 'No'), ('Yes', 'hmmm'), ('No', 'Idontknow'), ('No', 'Yes')])

In [73]: ('Yes', 'hmmm') in s
Out[73]: True
```

`timeit` comparison with `any()` :

```
In [77]: %timeit ('Yes', 'hmmm') in s
1000000 loops, best of 3: 428 ns per loop      #winner

In [78]: %timeit any(x[0]=="Yes" and x[-1]=="hmmm" for x in A)
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.87 us per loop
```

Comment: Will be good if you can edit your answer to suit my edited question.

Comment: `s=set(tuple(tuple([x[0],x[-1]]) for x in A))` takes about `5.6us` on my machine, so you really have to do some profiling to see if this speeds things up or not.

Comment: @root `set` creation is indeed a heavy operation, but considering if the list contains million items then `O(n)` look up using lists is certainly a bad idea.

Comment: Hmm.. Not a straight forward comparison. But I will be comparing three different types of combination. So I will just need to `set()` once for three times. So it's still worth it for me.

Comment: if you form a set `{tuple([x[0],x[-1]]) for x in A}` is almost twice as fast.

Comment: sorry for the spam, but `%timeit any({(x[0],x[-1]) == ('Yes','No') for x in A*10000})` is two time faster than the conversion itself :P

Comment: and `any(i[0]=='Yes' and i[2] == 'No' for i in A*10000)` actually seems to be the 10 times faster than than the conversion itself.

Answer (score 0):

Set doesn't support list, you can convert it into tuple,

```
A = [['Yes', 'No'], ['Yes', 'Idontknow'], ['No', 'Yes'], ['No', 'Idontknow']]
valid = ('Yes', 'No') in {tuple(item) for item in A}
```

and as @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams mentioned, the conversion from list to tuple is O(n), so if you are aware of performance, you need to choose other methods.

Comment: The conversion to set is O(n), so profiling is required before this is suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Following is how to do it using Set().

```
>>> A = Set([('Yes', 'No'), ('Yes', 'Idontknow'), ('No', 'Yes'), ('No', 'Idontknow')])
>>> ('Yes','No') in A
True
>>>
```

The elements of Set should be hashable.. so I have used tuples as Set elements and not lists.